# PayPal IPN simulator "We're sorry, we could not send an IPN."

Tags: paypal-ipn

I'm getting this answer when trying to use PayPal's IPN Simulator ("We're sorry, we could not send an IPN").

I know there are all kinds of ways I could be doing something wrong on my end, but I think I have covered all of them by now. My callback works when I send a POST request with dummy transaction data myself, from a computer in a different network than my server is in. There appears to be no firewall/proxy/connectivity/topology issues, server is there, port is open, and yet the simulator does not send IPNs.

I'm *NOT* using HTTPS and my server is *NOT* listening on port 80, does the IPN service has any restrictions on either protocol or port? If not I really have no idea what might be wrong.

Thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem was the use of a nonstandard port. This has been discussed in another post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088697/paypal-ipns-not-sending-being-received-on-sandbox

IPN Simulator error message is not that helpful though. Also, IPN documentation does not seem to mention port restrictions anywhere...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that the IPN simulator does not want to work on ports different than 80.

Also, you should check if you need to add additional headers like host (http 1.1) and connection close. I'm saying this because they are missing from the example script from paypal (PHP impl)

Comment: saved me a lot of time